# How to increase the dimensions of a NumPy arrray

Tags: python, numpy

I got the following array:

```
a = []

for i in range(5):
    a.append(np.array(range(5)))

a = np.array(a)

array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

I want to add an extra 'column' to the data, such that it looks like this:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

However, the only way I can think of is like the following. Is there not a better way?

```
a = np.array([np.insert(i,5,5) for i in a])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
np.hstack([a, np.ones((5,1))*5])
```

Output:

```
array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]])
```

Comment: Make the `ones` `int` dtype

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way using some other NumPy methods that might be useful to you in the future.

```
import numpy as np

# Creating the initial grid.
X = np.arange(5)
a, yy = np.meshgrid(X, X, sparse=False)

# Create an array of n repeating values; reshape it to (n, 1) dimensions.
newX = np.array([5] * 5).reshape((-1, 1))

# Append that sucker rowwise
np.append(a, newX, axis=1)
```